# Nginx server redirect to Error Server not working

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, reverse, custom-error-pages

I have been searching for a solution to this problem. Here is my setup.

Server A: 192.168.1.99

Nginx Server Latest version: 01-2020 version. Serves as Reverse proxy for all sites served by Server B.

Apache Server ( Serves two purposes): 1. Serve sites, 2. Serve as Error server if "Server B being down"

Server B: 192.168.1.100

Apache Server: Main Site Server.

Requirement:

When Server B is down, Server A should serve as an "Error page" with same domain name. For example:

if Server B serves: example.com,  and if it is down, then Server A will serve the error page as below:

example.com/error404.html
if the error is 502 error, it should serve example.com/error502.html from Server A.

Here is my configuration file:
Server A: (Nginx Server) /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf

```
server {
   listen 80;
   if ($host = www.example.com ) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
       #  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

   if ($host = example.com ) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
       #  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

   ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header  Host $host;
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_connect_timeout       300;
      proxy_send_timeout          300;
      proxy_read_timeout          300;
      send_timeout                300;
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      error_page 404 500 502 503 504 = @fallback;

      proxy_pass https://192.168.1.100:9443/;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;
     #rewrite http://www.example.com/ https://www.example.com/ redirect;
      proxy_redirect https://192.168.1.100:9443/ https://example.com;
  }

  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
  }

  location @fallback {
      root /var/www/example.com;
      rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com;
      #proxy_pass https://192.168.1.99:6443/;
      #proxy_redirect https://192.168.1.99:6443/ https://example.com;
      #rewrite ^/(.*) https://192.168.1.99:6443/  permanent;
  }


}
```

Comment: You don't specify the name of the error page anywhere. How does Nginx know to use `/error404.html` for 404 errors? The usual way is to use an `error_page 404 /error404.html;` and repeat for each of the status codes handled.

Comment: That syntax is for locally served files, here I’m routing the traffic to a fallback server, when backend server is down.

Comment: I think this can be achieved with load balancer setup.